# File not found error in Eclipse while using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, eclipse

I am using eclipse 2022-12 in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
While using spring boot i am facing java.io.FileNotFoundException with each xml and it is working fine with windows 10 and vscode in Ubuntu. Is there any solution?

I tried reinstalling it twice. Does I have to downgrade?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong that Eclipse is the problem. I suspct your code and setup is the problem and using wrong paths to load resources. But there is far too little information in your question to even begin answering it.

Comment: I don't know what to say but I permanently moved to VSCode and no longer use eclipse, I have been facing lot of issues. I have downgraded to Ubuntu20.04 but it still persists. I am using Avita NE14A2 Celeron btw. Hope it helps.